# TrueType Fonts in libGDX

Tags: java, android, fonts, truetype, libgdx

Does anyone know how I can use a TTF font in libGDX? I have looked around and have seen things about StbTrueTypeFont but it doesn't seem to be in the latest release.

EDIT: I found the StbTrueType font stuff, the jar file is located in the extensions directory. I've added it to my project. Now I just need to figure out how to use it. Any examples?

Comment: where can i get this library file? i've looked everywhere . the only places i've found (that didn't work ) are:
http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/extensions/stb-truetype/libs/stbtruetype-natives.jar?r=3031
http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/extensions/gdx-stb-truetype/libs/gdx-stb-truetype-natives.jar?r=3363

Comment: Go here: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/ and download the "libgdx-nightly-latest.zip" you will find the jars in the extensions directory.

Comment: which jars do i need to use ? i've tried to add "gdx-stb-truetype.jar" , but it keeps carshing and giving me exceptions , for example " javax.media.opengl.GLException: java.lang.NoClass
DefFoundError: com/badlogic/gdx/utils/SharedLibraryLoader ..."

Comment: You need `gdx-stb-truetype-natives.jar` and `gdx-stb-truetype.jar`. Add those both to your main project and make sure to add them to your build path.

Comment: still have the same error . i've even tried to use the other newest libraries that the desktop project wants but it didn't work(no error, but i can't see the text and some other things) :
gdx-backend-jogl-natives.jar
gdx-backend-jogl.jar
gdx-natives.jar
gdx-sources.jar
gdx-stb-truetype-natives.jar
gdx-stb-truetype.jar
gdx.jar

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes you will definitely need to add the `gdx-stb-truetype` jars to your project as you stated in your edit. Here is how you will use it, pretty straighforward...

First you need to declare your `BitmapFont` and the characters you will use...

```
BitmapFont font;
public static final String FONT_CHARACTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789][_!$%#@|\\/?-+=()*&.;,{}\"´`'<>";
```

Then you need to create the font...

```
font = TrueTypeFontFactory.createBitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font.ttf"), FONT_CHARACTERS, 12.5f, 7.5f, 1.0f, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
font.setColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
```

You can play with the arguments you pass to `createBitmapFont()` and you will see what they do.

Then to render the font you would do it as you normally do...

```
batch.begin();
font.draw(batch, "This is some text", 10, 10);
batch.end();
```

Comment: How can I use this font with ui elements such as `com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label`? Or does it impossible?

Comment: @uni As with any `BitmapFont`, you can apply to a `Label` by passing a `LabelStyle` in the `Label` constructor. In the `LabelStyle` you can specify a font. http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.html

Answer (score 28):

Use the gdx-freetype extension:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(fontFile);
BitmapFont font15 = generator.generateData(15);
BitmapFont font22 = generator.generateData(22);
generator.dispose();
```

"To use gdx-freetype, grab the latest nightlies, link `gdx-freetype.jar` and `gdx-freetype-natives.jar` to your desktop project, link `gdx-freetype.jar` to your Android project, and copy the `armeabi/libgdx-freetype.so` and `armeabi-v7a/libgdx-freetype.so` files to your Android project’s `libs/` folder, just like with the `libgdx.so` files."

Source: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2300

Comment: Is it possible to set the color of a BitmapFont generated this way? I couldn't use .setColor(rgb) on it.

Comment: @kelorek Tried `setColor(r, g, b, a)`? http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html

Comment: I do not recommend use it since it's not managed, then when your game resume all the text drawn using "this on-the-fly font" will be white.

Comment: Just to help clarify, those nightlies can be downloaded here: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/dist/extensions/gdx-freetype/

Answer (score 11):

Did researched a lot and found this working method:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("myfont.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = 12; // font size
BitmapFont font12 = generator.generateFont(parameter);
generator.dispose(); // avoid memory leaks, important
```

Use this if you failed tried answers above,
[libGDX Freetype Wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype) for reference.

Answer (score 3):

This is working on an S4 clone phone:
Pinewood is a downloaded font, in assets folder. See the folder structure below.

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator;

public class Game implements ApplicationListener {
    private SpriteBatch mSpriteBatch;
    private Texture textureBackground;
    private BitmapFont mBitmapFont;

    public void create() {

        Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
        Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();

        mSpriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

        Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false);
        textureBackground = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.jpg"));

        FileHandle fontFile = Gdx.files.internal("Pinewood.ttf");
        FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(fontFile);

        mBitmapFont = generator.generateFont(150);
        generator.dispose();

        mBitmapFont.setColor(0.9f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1); 
        Log.e("Game", "mBitmapFont.getScaleX() : "+mBitmapFont.getScaleX() + ", mBitmapFont.getScaleY() "+mBitmapFont.getScaleY());

    }

    public void render() {
        Log.e("Game", "render()");

        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // This cryptic line clears the screen.
        mSpriteBatch.begin();
        // Drawing goes here!
        mSpriteBatch.draw(textureBackground, 0, 0);
        mBitmapFont.draw(mSpriteBatch, "FPS:"+Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond(), 110, 260);
        mSpriteBatch.end();     
    }

    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    public void pause() {
    }

    public void resume() {
    }

    public void dispose() {
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to use FreeTypeFont library. [github](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype)

**1.as the github page say, for projects using gradle add this dependencies:**

Core Dependency:

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
```

Desktop Dependency:

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
```

Android Dependency:

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
```

for more details and platforms see [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#freetypefont-gradle) page

if you don't use gradle see [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype#user-content-how-to-put-gdx-freetype-in-your-project)

**2.after library added to your project you can use it like this:**

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("myfont.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = 12;
BitmapFont font12 = generator.generateFont(parameter); // font size 12 pixels
generator.dispose(); // don't forget to dispose to avoid memory leaks!
```

and put myfont.ttf in core assets folder