# TrueType fonts replaced with FreeType fonts in libgdx?

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx, game-engine

It seems like TrueType font and font generator is replaced with the FreeType font generator?  Is this truly the case, because I found this post detailing its usage (the accepted answer here: [TrueType Fonts in libGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486446/truetype-fonts-in-libgdx)), but can't find these JAR's anywhere in the latest sources (0.98 at the time of writing).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  TrueType font is replaced with freetype font. I don't understand why you are not able to find it, because in the link mentioned above they have already specified its path. Anyway, if you want to find the freetype jars then download latest nightly. Open it, and under the extension folder you will see gdx-freetype folder. Open it and use gdx-freetype.jar.

Comment: Thanks, turns out, I didn't follow the instructions, which once I followed these, it worked.  http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2300

Comment: Do you have problems with FreeType fonts? I've followed the tutorial, and it works fine, until Android app goes to onPause, after that fonts are lost, and the only thing that renders are white blocks with a lot of artifacts. :( help